# react-native-lightbox enables StatusBar

Tags: react-native, react-native-lightbox

I have implemented the `react-native-lightbox` but each time I click on a picture and a lightbox appears, it also enables the StatusBar I had set on hidden on the `Mainpage.js` (the lightbox is the `Detailview.js`)

```
    <StatusBar hidden={true} />
```

https://github.com/oblador/react-native-lightbox

```
<Lightbox activeProps={{resizeMode:"contain"}} ><Image source={{uri: image}} resizeMode="cover" style={Styles.image} /></Lightbox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed this by opening up `node_modules`, accessing `LightboxOverlay.js` and going to line 132 (as of version 0.6.0 -- find the `onClose` event) and changing `StatusBar.setHidden` to `true`

Comment: Thanks, this should be changed standard otherwise it will be overwritten by the first update

Comment: yeah--changing it every time we `npm install` is going to be annoying.